# How to cache SQL query results?

Tags: sql-server, caching, timeout

We display the SQL query results to UI, which gets execution time out in 2mins. The query takes 7-8 mins and sometimes 12 mins (worst case) in SSMS.

The result set contains one row as an output. It gets refreshed once daily, so caching can be done easily.

I have looked into the query execution plan, and the computation will require this much time (in short, the execution time won't come down below 2 mins even after optimization).

I have a few ideas to resolve this:

- **Materialized views**: It is not available now for SQL. (I'm unsure if Indexed views can help in this as data is being fetched from several tables and views, and all of the involved entities have indexes)
- **Quick (and dirty method)**: Run the query through the job agent
- **Caching the data**: I need ideas/suggestions around it, please.

Comment: Have you thought about using something like redis on the front end? What exactly takes 7-8 to 12 minutes to run? Is it the query itself, sending the data to the client, rendering, ...? SQL Server "caches" data in memory, but not query results. More details about what the query is doing and solving why it is slow is a much better approach than how do I cache the results. Even once a day a query that runs for 12 minutes suggests an opportunity for optimization.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron, for responding. The query takes 7-8mins to run in SSMS. Once I run it in SSMS then, if I rerun the same query in SSMS, it runs in 20 secs or less. I was hoping to use this as my base to resolve this issue.

Comment: Right, but that only touches the surface of _why_ it's slow. Watch [this video](https://erikdarlingdata.com/starting-sql-what-to-do-when-a-query-is-slow/) for starters, and see [this post](https://erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/).

Comment: So, I have already looked into the Query execution plan, and the computation will need that much time or maybe half, but still, we can't push it to less than 160 secs (as we are using nested queries and we have to do that to get few different columns). My main problem is not optimization; it is how to store the query results and retrieve them quickly, just like in materialized views.

Comment: I still think you are giving up on optimizing the queries for no reason, but I also think this is exactly what Redis and other front-end caching products were designed to solve. Why do you want to reinvent Redis inside SQL Server?

Comment: A table to hold the data would do the work for you. You can consider storing it in a [In-Memory OLTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/introduction-to-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver16), SQL Server 2014  and 2016 support it on Enterprise Edition, 2016SP1 and above support it for all editions

Comment: I have to agree with @AaronBertrand. This sounds a lot like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Fixing the cause of the performance is likely the best path. 12 minutes being the required amount of time is suspect unless you are talking about doing aggregates on joins between tables each having hundreds of millions of rows.

Comment: @Sean My car has square wheels, so it takes a long time to drive downtown, do you think I should buy a truck and a trailer so I can tow it downtown every day instead?

Comment: My bad if I haven't explained it earlier. This query is basically a view, which is getting data from another few joins over views, and further down one of it also have nested join over the same table. In short, there are around 3 tables and 3 views, and yes, aggregate is involved.
But I do understand what you and @AaronBertrand are saying. I will look into the queries further for optimization.
Thank you both for taking out to time and lending a hand for help! Really appreciate! :)

Comment: Aha!!! Nested views are very likely a MAJOR factor in why this is so slow. They seem so logical, but in reality they can cripple your query. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/performance-sql-server/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: @NewDeveloper if you add the actual execution plan to your Post (which you can do by uploading it to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)) I'm sure one of these experts, such as Aaron, can easily advise you on how to tune your query. I highly doubt that it can't be tuned to run in under 30 seconds (to throw an arbitrary but probably correct number out there). I've worked on much more complicated queries, 15 levels deep of nested views and queries, multiple aggregations, Row-Level Security, Replication, and more in the mix, that return in under 1 second.

Comment: Based on "The query takes 7-8mins to run in SSMS. Once I run it in SSMS then, if I rerun the same query in SSMS, it runs in 20 secs or less. " AND "This query is basically a view, which is getting data from another few joins over views, and further down one of it also have nested join over the same table." I can surmise that it is a large data processing / computation that scans a lot of data. I agree with OP that optimizing it would not be the best use of resources. Solution: SQL Server Agent -> Daily Job -> run your view and save to a table -> your code reads from this table.

Comment: @Alex I don't think you can surmise the type of computation based on what OP described. In fact, I think his clues are indicative that it's not a heavy computation if subsequent runs are quick. To me that indicates that he may be getting scans on larger tables (which may take time to load off disk) that potentially could be optimized into seeks instead. Perhaps the tipping point is being hit too eagerly, and maybe a better index could be used. *Optimize instead of compromise* is typically the better route to go.